# ASP.NET MVC Connection Problem (Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am working in syncfusion chart in ASP.NET MVC binding in SQL however I got a problem in connection string. I tried to Connect to SQL SERVER - Network related or Instance in SQl Server Configuration Manager and allow other apps in firewall but still not working.

[This is the error message in my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inZ2o.png)

Comment: Because you're new I'll be gentle. Search first and ask questions second - if you google your error message(s) you will get a ton of results, so don't ask questions which you could find yourself - we are not your mother nor your teacher.

Comment: I did search my problem but still not working  and that's my im asking for a guidance

Comment: 1) The "instance" does not exist 2) the database is not there or the datadirectory isn't what you think it is 3) try (really old-school) to connect with your database using an .udl file  (just create a text file onto your desktop rename the .txt to .udl and try to connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the server is up and can query data from SSMS, then most probable cause is that you did not allow remote connections. Try enabling that on your SQL server.

I would try to connect to that instance through SSMS from your debug machine first.